# A question about "Chilkat , XAdES-C , EncapsulatedTimeStamp"

Tags: c#, timestamp, xades, chilkat-xml

Below is my specific question.Thank you.

1. Does chilkat support generate XAdES-C?
2. What should I do if I want add EncapsulatedTimeStamp element into Signature?

Language: C#

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to send to Chilkat (info@chilkatsoft.com) a sample of valid, signed XML that is representative of what you want to produce.  Chilkat will then examine the XML and signature to see what, if anything, is not yet supported.  If something is not yet supported, it's likely easy to add.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have send a mail to info@chilkatsoft.com.